# How to check whether an object's class included a mixin in Dart?

Tags: dart, mixins

How do I check whether an object's class included a mixin? For example:

```dart
class AClass extends Object with MyMixin {}
class BClass extends Object              {}

classIncludesMixin(new AClass(), 'MyMixin'); // => true
classIncludesMixin(new BClass(), 'MyMixin'); // => false
```

What should be in this `classIncludesMixin()` method in order for it to work?

Comment: You really want reflect class (mixin) by its name? E.g., you want use 'MyMixin' instead of runtime type `MyMixin`? If you want to use `name` instead of `type` then in this case you must determine `library` where this class resides and later compare both `name and library`. Comparing only name may be not correct in some cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply use a type check `o is MyMixin` (that will be also true for inheritance and implementation).

If you really have to check the mixin clause you have to use [dart:mirrors](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors.html) :

```dart
bool classIncludesMixin(o, String mixinName) {
  var c = reflect(o).type;
  while (c != null) {
    var m = c.mixin;
    if (c != m && m.simpleName == new Symbol(mixinName)) return true;
    c = c.superclass;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you know a way with dart:mirrors? As `o is MyMixin` also returns true if o implements or extends and of course itself is `MyMixin`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreArdhuin that's great. It seems I have always overlooked that `mixin` getter. What I find interesting is, that `classInclusesMixin(new MyMixin(), 'MyMixin')` returns true as well.

Comment: Or an issue of `dart:mirrors`?

Comment: Considering the [ClassMirror#mixin](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/ClassMirror.html#mixin) documentation I would say it's my code. I fixed it.

Comment: Great! Sorry can't upvode more than once ;-)